# EventSetters in wpf code + VB.net

Tags: .net, rfc2445

I have to add event setter to a style in code behind file in `VB.NET`.

While adding event setter we have to pass 2 arguments.

1. is system.windows.routedevent
2. system.delegate.

I am unable to pass `system.delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `Delegate` with the correct signature first:

```
Delegate Sub HandlerDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
```

Then create a method in your class matching that signature

```
Private Sub MyHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Now you can define a variable of `HandlerDelegate` type, assign your method to it and pass it to `EventSetter` constructor:

```
Dim handler As HandlerDelegate
handler = AddressOf Me.MyHandler

Dim setter As EventSetter
setter = New EventSetter(routedEvent, handler)
```